# VBA functions returning collection - error argument not optional

Tags: excel, vba, object, collections, return

i'm have a function that gets a string as parameter and should return a collection, but it doesn't work. I get an error dialog "compile error: argument not optional"
What am i doing wrong?

```
Sub Test()
    
    Dim c as Collection
    Set c = New Collection
    c = DoThingsInColl("testsheet")

End Sub

Function DoThingsInColl(val as String) as Collection
    
    Dim myColl as Collection
    Set myColl = New Collection
    Sheets.Item(val).Select
    --- things that changes myColl based on the sheet values---
    Set DoThingsInColl = myColl

End Function
```

Comment: yeah sorry was a typo when pasting on here! thanks

Comment: fixed typos made while pasting

Comment: You are returning a Collection to variable c, therefore you need 'Set c = DoThingsInColl(.....''

Comment: You need to use `Set` when assigning the return value to `c`

Comment: Thanks @FunThomas, if u add a reply i'll give u the green check also